# What would be a good DAO pattern to combine with Dependency Injection for a PHP framework?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dao

I am developing a PHP framework, based on dependency injection. My data objects are injectable components, like any others.

I have an abstract DAO class, that each model should extend, that has:

- basic crud methods
- a reference to DI container, to instantiate objects

Things are, in short, like this

```
abstract class AbstractDao {
  protected $fields;
  protected $container; // This is the (injected) DI container, used to create instances.
  protected $driver; // The injected database driver (i.e. PDO)
  public function insert() {
    // Insert implementation
    // Insert current instance.
  }
  public function fetch($id) {
    // Fetch implementation
    // Fetches a row and sets fields on current instance
  }
  public function fetchAll() {
    // Performs a select * query on database driver
    // Iterates through results, and creates an instance
    // for each result using $container, like this:
    foreach ($results as $row) {
      // I can't just make $instances[] = new Something(), or all the
      // dependency injection thing would mess up.
      $instances[] = $this->container->get('someDao');
    }
    return $instances;
  }
  // Other methods.
}

class Book extends AbstractDao {
  protected $fields = array('field', 'definition', 'goes', 'here',);
  // No special behaviour is needed, so we can keep default
  // abstract implementation without overriding.
}
```

My question: every data object implementation (a book, a person, an user, etc.) must extend my AbstractDao object, **therefore it will carry the weight** of $driver and $container. Furthermore, since $fields property is defined at instance level, each data object would have its own, adding more overhead.

I fear that when handling big data sets this solution may result in a much expensive one, in terms of performance. I know objects would be just referenced, not cloned, but the overhead could be sadly high.

Couple of solutions i have in mind are

- using static method implementations, that may reduce overhead in
  subclasses
- do not make my Daos extends the above mentioned AbstractDao, that should become a sort of DaoProvider. In this case, for each method, i should pass in the instance (thing that i don't really like)

None of those solutions i like that much... first i don't like using static things, as they conflicts a little with the entire idea of injection. Second, i dont like the idea of removing the dao subclassing pattern.

Any good idea would be really appreciated, thank you.

**=== EDIT ===**

One more thing that came to my mind. What i don't like in the 2nd approach ("dao provider") is that the provider has to perform operations on Dao fields (set values, set status, set isDirty, etc.), therefore fields have to be made accessible from outside. With the subclassing approach one can keep those protected or private.

**=== /EDIT ===**

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a DAO Interface that declares behavior that a DAO implementation will have to define. Now in each concrete DAO implementation you can define your `$driver`, `$container` and `$fields`instance fields.

After that you might want to create a `AbstractModel`class that each concrete model should extend so that both your `AbstractModel`and concrete models be will 'data access agnostic'. The `AbstractModel` class will end up looking like this:

```
/*
* an AbstractModel
*/
abstract class AbstractModel {

    protected $daoImpl;

    function __construct(DAOInterface $daoImpl) {
        $this->daoImpl = $daoImpl;
    }

    //some other functions that are common to concrete models
}

/*
* a concrete model
*/
class Model extends AbstractModel {

    function findAll($params) {
        //You can use the $daoImpl of AbstractModel to perform a CRUD operation
        $this->daoImpl->findAll($params);
    }

}
```

Now whenever you instantiate a concrete model you will inject a DAO implementation into the model class.

```
//inject a DAOInterface implementation into Model
$model = new Model(new DAOImpl());
$model->findAll($params);
```

The advantage here is that you can stub different DAO implementations during testing and perhaps this is where the DI container comes in handy. There's a [similar code sample](https://github.com/tafadzwagonera/dutu/blob/master/tests/test.php) I have created when I was creating my DI container a few days ago.

BTW I don't see the need of putting a `$container`object inside your AbstractDAO why don't you pass in an object that is returned when you invoke a property of the container. That way you can use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to force the object parameters to be of a certain type and encourage a fail-fast mechanism if a wrong object is passed in and you might also find it beneficial to create a Config class to handle your `$driver` details so that users are free to configure the driver they want to use for the db.

Comment: Thank you Tifa, im studying your proposed solution amongst others. Please see edit, there's a new issue i forgot to mention.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, setters expose the state of an object thus tend to break encapsulation since any class can inadvertently modify the state of your object. I would consider the sub-classing approach a better implementation of the two in this context.